# netlink: GNEL_ID_GENERATE definition removed from RHEL7.5 kernel library

Tags: linux, kernel, ipc

We have a kernel module that was building fine for RedHat family of Linux distribution, until the recent RHEL7.5.

When trying to build on RHEL7.5, we've got an error of:

...error: ‘GENL_ID_GENERATE’ undeclared...

Did some reading, and it seems like this is an change since kernel 4.11+, but RHEL7.5 is based on kernel 3.10+. What happened?

Anyway, I know that the value of GENL_ID_GENERATE is simply 0. But can I used use 0 to replace the macro? Will there be a problem with user mode module to communicate with this kernel module?

Or, what should be the proper way to fix the problem? Any advice?

Thanks and regards,
Weishan

Comment: Were you using this to fill the `.id` field of a `struct genl_family`? If so, [looking at the `git` commits](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/bwh/linux-stable.git/commit/?id=a07ea4d9941af5a0c6f0be2a71b51ac9c083c5e5) it looks like you can omit the `.id` completely; the patch removed static family IDs for netlink.

Comment: Thank you, Erik. Yes, that is just to fill the .id field of a struct genl_family. The information you provided is very helpful.

Comment: Hum... Beside this issue, there's another problem:

error: implicit declaration of function ‘genl_register_family_with_ops’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  retval = res_link_genl_register_family_with_ops(&res_link_genl_family, res_link_gnl_ops, ARRAY_SIZE(res_link_gnl_ops));
  ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors

I have made the build pass, by turn off that warning message as error. However, the kernel module I've build cannot be loaded properly. Seems like this is a issue that need to be addressed. Is that because of some DKMS update? Is that to patch the CPU risk?

Comment: It's noted in [the Linux HOWTO documentation for netlink](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/generic_netlink_howto): "include a reference to your genl_ops struct as an element in the genl_family struct (element .ops), as well as the number of commands (element .n_ops)." Once you indicate that the issue is fixed, I'll make an answer so you can mark it as complete so other people with the same issue can more easily find it :-)

Comment: Hi Erik, Thank you so much for your help so far. I'm in a more complex situation: our kernel module will need to support different version and distribution of Linux. At beginning, we have the compiler operation: #if LINUX_VERSION_CODE > KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,30) to define what we do with genl_register_family..., and it is would be logical to add a && (LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(3,12,0)). But the recent Kernel update /RHEL update make this changed from 7.4 (3.10.0-693) and 7.5 (3.10.0-862). How can I check the kernel build number (-693 v.s. -862) with pre-compile operation?

Comment: Hi Erik, just to update you in short, the information you've provided is what I'm looking for, and has resolved my problem. For the moment, I use the RHEL_RELEASE_CODE >= RHEL_RELEASE_VERSION(7,5) to deal with the mass of versioning, and it would work for now. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Oh, no... I speak too quick. Now, the user mode component cannot communicate with the kernel module any more X~D 
With netLink->Send, I get NLMSG_ERROR. Will take further look into this.

Comment: Hi Erik, I think you can make an answer and I'll mark it as complete. For the communication problem after the kernel module successfully loaded, that will be a different problem and I'll do some further troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the git commits](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/bwh/linux-stable.git/commit/?id=a07ea4d9941af5a0c6f0be2a71b51ac9c083c5e5) for netlink it looks like several changes were made to the structure in version 4.11:

First, you can omit the `.id` field completely from your initializer in `genl_family` as Linux has removed static family IDs.

As well, the `genl_register_family_with_ops` function is not used any more. Instead, as [noted in the Linux HOWTO documentation for netlink](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/generic_netlink_howto#registering-a-family):

> Up to linux 4.10, use `genl_register_family_with_ops()`. On 4.10 and
>   later, include a reference to your `genl_ops` struct as an element in
>   the `genl_family` struct (element `.ops`), as well as the number of
>   commands (element `.n_ops`).

Comment: This resolved my problem of cannot build and load the kernel module successfully for RHEL7.5. What really confused me, is that RedHat has port this part of change to the kernel 3.10.0-862(RHEL7.5). Even worse, they didn't document this change properly, and they even keep using the same the kernel version (3.10.0).